# Creating custom component with <img> for markdown gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, markdown, gatsby

I'm trying to create a custom component for my markdown that accepts an image source. I am unable to display the image via the custom component because the image is not found because it doesn't exist

I also realised the image path is generated by GatsbyJS and I have no idea how to retrieve the path of the image in markdown.

I do have a custom component that holds some text but I couldn't do the same thing for images.

Here is a simple markdown with a title and a few words.

index.md

```
---
title: ToDoApp
---

Hi this is my todoapp app. Below is a bunch of screens

<imageholder src='./screen1.png'></imageholder>
![Image from Gyazo](./screen1.png) <!-- it displays... -->
```

I've created a custom component named imageholder where it holds some logic (in a near future...) in displaying the image

ImageHolder.js

```
import React from "react"
   export default class ImageHolder extends React.Component {
   render() {
     return (
       <img src={this.props.src} alt="Logo"/>
     )
   }
 }
```

project-post.js

```
const renderAst = new rehypeReact({
  createElement: React.createElement,
  components: {
   "imageholder": ImageHolder
  },
}).Compiler
```

And I received this...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really tricky since (AFAIK) you can't pass props from page component to custom component with `rehype-react`. I think you'd need to do something similar to `gatsby-remark-images`, which locates the images' paths and set them.

I wrote [this plugin](https://github.com/d4rekanguok/gatsby-remark-custom-image-component) that mimics `gatsby-remark-images`, but for custom components like in your case.

Here's the default setting, you can override the component name and pass in additional image transformation options.

```
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-custom-image-component`,
            options: {
              // plugin options
              componentName: 'image-wrapper',
              imagePropName: 'src',
              sharpMethod: 'fluid',
              // fluid's arguments, see gatsby-plugin-sharp docs
              quality: 50,
              maxWidth: 800,
            }
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

Then use it in your markdown:

```
<image-wrapper src='./hero.jpg'></image-wrapper>
```

And get the image props in your custom component.

```
//src/components/ImageWrapper.js
import React from 'react'

// the result of sharp's image transformation will be passed directly to this component.
// so if you use `fluid` as `sharpMethod`, you'll get
// src, srcSet, base64, aspectRatio, srcSetType, sizes, density, originalImage. 
// Please refer to `gatsby-plugin-sharp` docs.
const ImageWrapper =  ({ src, srcSet }) => <img src={src} srcSet={srcSet} />

export { ImageWrapper }
```

Comment: Thank you Derek! Was wondering do your plugin accept multiple images source? Awesome plugin by the way

Comment: @Harrizontal I'm glad you found it helpful! It doesn't accept multiple image sources, but might not be difficult to add. What is your use case & what syntax do you imagine it'd look like?

Comment: I am trying to create some kind of grid for the images - the different amount of images have different grid style applied - hence, I believe custom component for markdown does work for this use case. I also would like to put some text beside the image... I didn't approach the inline styles e.g div class='row',etc - like the bootstrap kind, because it might affect the readability in the markdown (probably I might be too strict on this...). 

I couldn't think of a good syntax but this could work right..?
<image-wrapper src='./hero.jpg' src2='./hero2.jpg'></image-wrapper>

Comment: Sorry for the long text. I am beginner in React, and new to Gatsby. Wish could contribute to your project in near future...

Comment: gotcha, I'll look into adding something like that. You might also want to check out [mdx](https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx), which allows you to write jsx in md -- I haven't really used it, but it might be helpful for what you want to do!

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that props are passed as strings to rehype - the component doesn't receive the asset hashed value when the markdown is processed and built by Gatsby. So, the prop isn't the same as the image tag's src once you build the site, and it's not finding the asset hashed file.

This plugin, [Gatsby Remark Copy Linked Files](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files), moves your referenced asset files to a `public` folder, and passes the correctly hashed asset path, but by default only for **img, a, audio, and video** tags (not for custom components).

To solve for this, move the plugin from node_modules into a /plugin folder in the project root, and add the desired custom components and props at [this line](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/5dfb5b907ad8418f75b39f8aff4c384717bb083b/packages/gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files/src/index.js#L271). In your case, it looks like it would be:

```
// Handle a tags.
extractUrlAttributeAndElement($(`a[href]`), `href`).forEach(processUrl)

// Manually added custom tags
extractUrlAttributeAndElement($(`imageholder[src]`), `src`).forEach(processUrl)
```

Obviously this would be better served as an option for the plugin in a configuration block in `gatsby-config`, but this worked for me in a pinch.